# Filtering on multiple values in function

Tags: postgresql

The non-functional version of my problem is easy: I want to filter values based upon whether a text variable has some specific values:

```
SELECT routine_name, data_type
  FROM information_schema.routines
   WHERE data_type IN ('boolean', 'integer');
```

Since I want to do many variations on what I'm filtering on, I want to have a function that accepts the values to filter on.  My attempt at turning this into a function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_fns_by_data_type(data_types text[])
  RETURNS TABLE(routine_name text, data_type text) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT routine_name, data_type
    FROM information_schema.routines
    WHERE data_type IN (array_to_string($1, ','));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call it:

```
SELECT * FROM get_fns_by_data_type(ARRAY['boolean', 'integer'])
```

I get no results.

I suspect that somehow I should be quoting the values, but I'm not sure of the best approach to this, nor how to debug the problem.

How do I use the array in my `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_to_string` returns a single string, not a list of string, so in your function you are actually running:

```
where data_type IN ('boolean, integer')
```

(which is clearly not what you intended)

You don't need convert the array in the first place. You can use it directly

```
where data_type = any ($1)
```